# How do I specify an empty interface as a generic argument in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, eslint

I have a React Component in Typescript. This component has a State but no Properties. I have the following code:

```
interface State { ... }

class MyComponent extends React.Component<{}, State> { ... }
```

Today I moved from `tslint` to `eslint`, and got a warning, saying I should not use `{}` as a type.

When I created an empty interface:

```
interface Prop { }
```

And passed that as the first generic argument, I got another warning, saying an empty interface is the same as `{}`.

So, what should I do? I can't use `never` since it causes a whole bunch of other errors, please - it really doesn't make sense here. Is there any alternative to disabling the `ban-types` rule?

Comment: I don't use react so I'm not sure what purpose `{}` serves as the prop type, but if you're doing it on purpose and understand what you're doing, then your configuration of the `ban-types` rule is probably too aggressive.

Comment: I'm using `{}` to say "no properties".

Comment: Use `unknown` as your prop type.

Comment: you can use `unknown` to `never` as the type beside `any` if you don't use strict mode in tsconfig.json

Comment: I can use unknown, but it really makes little sense here, as the interface is fully known - it's just empty.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the component to be able to parent other components, you might want to accept the `children` key even if it doesn't have other props.

Your code would then look as below and wouldn't be passing an empty spec for props...

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<{ children?: ReactNode }, State> { ... }
```